# Need to build inbound integration (webhook) to receive and decrypt (AES256) data

Tags: namedcredentials, inboundservices, remote-site-settings

I've built many inbound integrations where an external system (e.g. Twilio) sends data to a webhook (https site URL setup on Salesforce, with Public Access to an Apex class) that handles that inbound data.

I'm being asked to build one where the inbound data is AES256 encrypted. I'll need to decrypt it and handle the data.

I've read through the [Crypto Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) docs and see the decrypt methods to use. However, I'm missing the overview that explains how to get the key and the IV (initialization vector) parameters. Are these parameters static, like an API key, or are they dynamically generated? Are they stored in the org as a Named Credential, Remote Site Setting or Custom Metadata, or maybe a derived algorithm from the datetime or something?

I'm trying to understand what I'll need to ask the devs who built the system that is making the inbound calls. I don't mind the research, but I can't seem to find an explanation that starts with some basics.

Comment: They're static. Since AES is a symmetric algo, the key is shared between sender and recipient, either party can generate it.  All you need to tell them is that SF supports AES-256 in CBC mode with PKCS7 padding.

Comment: Where is the safest place to save it, or does it matter? And what about the IV, or should I use the ManagedIV option?

Comment: Safest: protected custom metadata or protected custom setting, see [Storing Sensitive Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_storing_sensitive_data.htm). IV is not secret in CBC mode, so managed vs not managed doesn't matter, pick one that you and your devs are comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. You put it all in Comments, so I can't upvote you...